# Differentiate the following function..

Tags: calculus

I am trying to Differentiate the following:

$$s=4e^{3t}-2e^{-3t}$$

I have this Answer

$$\frac{ds}{dt}=12e^{3t}+6e^{3t}$$

Is this answer correct?

And is it the correct working out?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $s=4e^{3t}-2e^{-3t}$ and $\frac{ds}{dt}=12e^{3t}+6e^{3t}$? If so, it's incorrect.

Comment: Yes I mean that. Is that the correct way to show workings out? Because it seems to short. Thanks.

Comment: @Liam You are missing a "$-$". It would become more clear if you went through it step by step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct (except for a missing minus sign on the second exponent). I don't know how much working you need to show, but it might be good (at the elementary levels) to show your step by step working with chain rule:

$$s=4e^{3t}-2e^{-3t}$$

$$\frac{ds}{dt} = 4(3)e^{3t} - 2(-3)e^{-3t}$$

$$\frac{ds}{dt} = 12e^{3t} + 6e^{-3t}$$

Comment: Thank you. So it is a chain rule? Just wan to know so I can lean chain rule. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is a simple application of chain rule (once on each term).

Comment: Thank you. Is that the full workings out with the chain rule that you have done?

Comment: @Liam I think it is acceptable, but this depends on your teacher. You can write it out even more verbosely but I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. I can now learn it and try some different functions.